# How to convert status of the user from Django Administration Page

Tags: django, django-registration, django-login

I want to change the status of a registered user to `staff` or `active/notactive`. While logging in the `Django Administration` Page as a superuser I couldn't find any option to do that as you can see from the below screen shot. How can we do it.

[image]

Comment: click on the user you want to change the status for and in the details page you will get a is_staff flag,

Comment: @Exprator Thanks forgot to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Exprator Suggestion and it worked